# jOOQ: How to get "coalesce()" to render with "format json" when used in DSL.jsonEntry() and Oracle dialect

Tags: jooq

Hitting a very niche usecase limitation/bug when attempting to use `coalesce()` and requiring that it be appended with `format json` in Oracle.

The following code describes the issue:

- `RENDERED 1` is correct, but `as varchar2(4000)` gets appended when used inside of `DSL.jsonEntry()`

The desired output is:

```sql
key ? value coalesce("foo", to_clob('{ "rows": [] }')) format json
```

```kotlin
import org.jooq.SQLDialect
import org.jooq.impl.DSL
import org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType

val dsl = DSL.using(SQLDialect.ORACLE21C)

val stmt1 = DSL.field(
    "{0} format json",
    DSL.coalesce(
        DSL.field(DSL.name("foo"), SQLDataType.CLOB),
        DSL.cast(DSL.inline("{ \"rows\": [] }"), SQLDataType.CLOB)
    )
)

val stmt2 = DSL.cast(
    DSL.coalesce(
        DSL.field(DSL.name("foo"), SQLDataType.CLOB),
        DSL.cast(DSL.inline("{ \"rows\": [] }"), SQLDataType.CLOB)
    ),
    SQLDataType.JSON
)

val composed1 = DSL.jsonEntry("key", stmt1)
val composed2 = DSL.jsonEntry("key", stmt2)

// RENDERED 1: coalesce("foo", to_clob('{ "rows": [] }')) format json
println("RENDERED 1: ${dsl.render(stmt1)}")

// RENDERED 2: cast(coalesce("foo", to_clob('{ "rows": [] }')) as json)
println("RENDERED 2: ${dsl.render(stmt2)}")

// RENDERED 3: key ? value cast(coalesce("foo", to_clob('{ "rows": [] }')) format json as varchar2(4000))
println("RENDERED 3: ${dsl.render(composed1)}")

// RENDERED 4: key ? value cast(coalesce("foo", to_clob('{ "rows": [] }')) as json) format json
println("RENDERED 4: ${dsl.render(composed2)}")
```

Comment: A `JSONEntry` isn't a standalone `QueryPart`, outside of a `JSON_OBJECT` call, at least it wasn't designed for this usage. In my experience, the various `JSON_OBJECT` implementations provide a ton of important context that will modify `JSONEntry` content, so I don't think it can decide on its own that `FORMAT JSON` will be necessary. So, you probably have an entirely different question than the one you've asked, namely, how to best do X, whereas this question is about Y, an attempt of yours to do X, but I can't really answer Y. I could answer X, though?

Comment: Thanks Lukas for replying, I was able to get it to work eventually fortunately (see below)

Comment: OK, let me know if you think jOOQ does something wrong, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by wrapping it in a `CustomField`, see below:

```kotlin
fun oracleCoalesceFormatJson(field: Field<*>) = CustomField.of("coalesce_format_json", SQLDataType.JSON) { ctx ->
        ctx.visit(DSL.field("{0}", field))
    }

DSL.jsonEntry(
    alias.value,
    oracleCoalesceFormatJson(
        DSL.coalesce(
            DSL.field(DSL.name("name"), SQLDataType.CLOB),
            DSL.cast(DSL.inline("{ \"rows\": [] }"), SQLDataType.CLOB)
        )
    )
)
```

Not great but hey, it works.